How to pass parameters from a text file to PowerShell script
I have a script - Master.ps1:
Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple  @{"Address"="xx.xx.x.xxx";"Network"="Cluster Network 1";"SubnetMask"="zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz"};
Get-ClusterResource "SQL IP Address 1 (Host-Name-SQL)" | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple @{"Address"="xx.xx.x.yyy";"Network"="Cluster Network 1";"SubnetMask"="zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz"};
Start-ClusterResource -Name "CLuster IP Address";
Start-ClusterResource -Name "CLuster Name";
Start-ClusterResource -Name "SQL Server" -Wait 0;
Start-ClusterResource -Name "SQL Server Agent"

I also have a file PS_Param.txt with parameters:
param(
$ClusterIP="CLuster IP Address",
$Address1="xx.xx.x.xxx",
$Network1="Cluster Network 1",
$SubnetMask1="zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz",
$SQLServer="SQL IP Address 1 (Host-Name-SQL)",
$Address2="xx.xx.x.yyy",
$Network2="Cluster Network 1",
$SubnetMask2="zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz"
)

I created a new script - Master-Param.ps1:
param(
[string]$ClusterIP,
[string]$Address1,
[string]$Network1,
[string]$SubnetMask1,
[string]$SQLServer,
[string]$Address2,
[string]$Network2,
[string]$SubnetMask2
)
Get-ClusterResource $ClusterIP | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple @{"Address"=$Address1;"Network"=$Network1;"SubnetMask"=$SubnetMask1};
Get-ClusterResource $SQLServer | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple @{"Address"=$Address2;"Network"=$Network2;"SubnetMask"=$SubnetMask2};
Start-ClusterResource -Name "CLuster IP Address";
Start-ClusterResource -Name "CLuster Name";
Start-ClusterResource -Name "SQL Server" -Wait 0;
Start-ClusterResource -Name "SQL Server Agent"

So, it works if I run it like this:
Master-Param.ps1 "Cluster IP Address" "xx.xx.x.xxx" "Cluster Network 1" "zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz" "SQL IP Address 1 (Host-Name-SQL)" "xx.xx.x.yyy" "Cluster Network 1" "zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz" -Verb RunAs -Force
I want to pass the actual values of the parameters from PS_Param.txt directly into a Master-Param.ps1, so I don't have to list all the values in a command line and if anything changes (like IPs or names), I only have a txt file to edit.
I would really appreciate any help I could get.
I really cannot find any information on how to accomplish what I want to do and if it's even possible.
I would appreciate any help or maybe pointing me to a right direction.

Change your PS_Param.txt to PS_Param.psd1 or PS_Param.ps1 and change the structure from a param block to a single hashtable:
@{
    ClusterIP   = 'CLuster IP Address'
    Address1    = 'xx.xx.x.xxx'
    Network1    = 'Cluster Network 1'
    SubnetMask1 = 'zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz'
    SQLServer   = 'SQL IP Address 1 (Host-Name-SQL)'
    Address2    = 'xx.xx.x.yyy'
    Network2    = 'Cluster Network 1'
    SubnetMask2 = 'zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz'
}

Then you can first use Import-PowerShellDataFile to get the parameters and later on call your script binding arguments via hashtable splatting:
$myParams = Import-PowerShellDataFile path\to\PS_Param.psd1
Master-Param.ps1 @myParams


Here's one way you could do this. Suppose the following script:
# Test-Script.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [String]
  $Param1,

  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [String]
  $Param2
)

Write-Host ('$Param1 = "{0}"' -f $Param1)
Write-Host ('$Param2 = "{0}"' -f $Param2)

You can create a text file, e.g. Params.txt, containing the parameter data:
Param1=Parameter value 1
Param2=Parameter value 2

You can import this text file as a single hashtable; e.g.:
$Params = (Get-Content Params.txt) -join [Environment]::NewLine | ConvertFrom-StringData

(The -join operator treats the content of the Params.txt file as a single input instead of creating two hashtables.)
Lastly, you can 'splat' the parameters to the script:
Test-Script @Params

The script output will be:
$Param1 = "Parameter value 1"
$Param2 = "Parameter value 2"

This technique might be handy for scripts that require a large number of parameters.

Get-Content Params.txt -join [Environment]::NewLine would throw a parameter binding exception. it needs parentheses so the expression can be evaluated, however -Raw is much easier in this case

(Get-Content Params.txt -join [Environment]::NewLine) should be (Get-Content Params.txt) -join [Environment]::NewLine

Right: Closing paren was in the wrong place. Fixed.

Thank you for responding.
I got it working like this:
param(
$current_path='G:\MyPath
)
    
Get-Content "$current_path\PS_param.txt" | foreach-object -begin {$h=@{}} -process { $k = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($k[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($k[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True)) { $h.Add($k[0], $k[1]) } }
    
    $ClusterIP = $h.Get_Item("ClusterIP")
    $SQLServer = $h.Get_Item("SQLServer")
    $AddressCL = $h.Get_Item("AddressCL")
    $AddressSQL = $h.Get_Item("AddressSQL")
    $Network1 = $h.Get_Item("Network1")
    $Network2 = $h.Get_Item("Network2")
    $SubnetMask1 = $h.Get_Item("SubnetMask1")
    $SubnetMask2 = $h.Get_Item("SubnetMask2")

Now, the question is - if I have to put a path into this scrip anyway, why would I need a parameter for it ("$current_path\PS_param.txt")?
If I move or rename .txt file, I need to go inside this scrip anyway and change it here.
I am trying to make this main script run with the parameter file that can be easily modified without touching the main ps1 script (or touch it as little as possible).  I hope I am explaining this right.
Thank you in advance for your help.
